# Warning: The `value` prop is required for the `<Context.Provider>`. Did you misspell it or forget to pass it? react js

Tags: reactjs

```
import NoteContext from './noteContext';
import { useState } from 'react';

const NoteState = (props)=>{
    const s1 ={
        "name": "Vishal",
        "class": "5b"
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(s1);
    const update =()=>{
         setTimeout(() => {
             setState({
                 "name":"Aamit",
                 "class":"6b"
             })
         }, 1000);   
    }
    
    return (
        <NoteContext.Provider  values={{state,update}}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default NoteState;
```

Comment: You have a typo. `values={{state,update}}` should be `value={{state,update}}`.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments mentioned, you have a typo. `values={{state,update}}` should be `value={{state,update}}`

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what the OP did, but I was passing the values as individual props instead of in the `value` prop.

**Wrong**

```
<NoteContext.Provider variant={variant} foo={bar}>
  {children}
</NoteContext.Provider>
```

**Right**

```
<NoteContext.Provider value={{variant, foo: bar}}>
  {children}
</NoteContext.Provider>
```